# How to update the column value in sql based on other column value

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have data like below

| Amount | currency | Investors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 250 | USD | Coinvest I |
| 0 | GBP | Coinvest I |
| 860 | USD | Paralell |
| 0 | GBP | Paralell |
| 121 | USD | PSLO |
| 5 | NULL | PSLO |

I need output like below

| Amount | currency | Investors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 250 | GBP | Coinvest I |
| 860 | GBP | Paralell |
| 126 | USD | PSLO |

i.e scenario - I want to club/group by Investors and aggregate amount and currency field should be when its USD or Null it should be USD or when its GBP or USD it should display GBP.

Query is not working:

```sql
select sum(Amount)  
case when currency in ('USD' , NULL ) then 'USD'
else currency end as c1, Investors
from table 
group by c1 , Investors;
```

Tried:

```sql
select sum(Amount)  
case when currency in ('USD' , NULL ) then 'USD'
else currency end as c1, Investors
from table 
group by c1 , Investors;
```

Comment: It works out here, because the only places where USD and GBP mix one of the values is 0. But if you have actual data for both currencies, a simple `SUM()` seems like it would give bad results.

Comment: "UPDATE" has a very specific meaning in SQL, and what you are doing is **NOT** an UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

For this exact case you can use `sum` fro amount, and `min` fro currency.

```sql
select sum(Amount) amount,
    min(currency),
    Investors
from table 
group by Investors
```

Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/LTTsHcsu).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `row_number()` for prioritization:

```
select amount, currency, investors
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by investors
            order by case currency
                when 'GBP' then 1
                when 'USD' then 2
                else 3
            end
        ) rn
    from mytable
) t
where rn = 1
```

When an investor has more than one row, this puts first the row with 'GBP', then 'USD', and then other values (here, `null`). You can easily adapt the `case` expression to take in account more currencies or a different prioritization sequence.

Comment: This query select value associated with selected currency. But based on example of output I believe it should be sum of all values.